# Convert string to array value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string-parsing

If I had an array such as:

```
testarray = array('foo'=>34, 'bar'=>array(1, 2, 3));
```

How would I go about converting a string such as `testarray[bar][0]` to find the value its describing?

Comment: look on eval http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: What are you trying to do? There may be better ways to do this

Comment: I agree with @Pekka -- I can't imagine a use-case for this that would be considered good practice.

Comment: I have a function that takes a parameter of a $_POST value and validates it, however it won't work with field values that are arrays, because $_POST['testfield[0][foo]'] != $_POST[testfield][0][foo]

Comment: You may want to prepend a $ to you variable name.

Comment: an array means equal actions. Othwerwise it shouldn't be an array. Why can't your function accept an array as well?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do something like this (Not the prettiest, but far safer than `eval`)...:

```
$string = "testarray[bar][0]";

$variableBlock = '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*';
$regex = '/^('.$variableBlock.')((\[\w+\])*)$/';
if (preg_match($regex, $string, $match)) {
    $variableName = $match[1]; // "testarray"
    if (!isset($$variableName)) {
        //Error, the variable does not exist
        return null;
    } else {
        $array = $$variableName;
        if (preg_match_all('/\[(\w+)\]/', $match[2], $matches)) {
            foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
                if (!is_array($array)) {
                    $array = null;
                    break;
                }
                $array = isset($array[$match]) ? $array[$match] : null;
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
} else {
    //error, not in correct format
}
```

Comment: while the OP can achieve his goal by just calling `check_post(&$_POST[testfield][0][foo]);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP's eval function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

However, make absolutely sure the input is sanitized!

Cheers